# Viewpager pages are not remain as such even if popstacking/backpressed

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, onbackpressed

I have a fragment with ViewPager.The ViewPager contain 2 fragments(A and B).Fragment A contain an expandable list view.When I clicked an item in expandable list,it will got to another fragment.When I click back,it will popstack and show the the viewpager fragment.It works fine.But my problem is,when it is popstacked,the viewpager is reloading and it shows like the first time.I want to remain the expandable list view open as it is clicked when popstacked.I have spent lot of time on this.Can any one help me?

ReadingFragment ie.the main fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reading, container, false);
     readingviewpager=mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.readingviewpager);
    readingviewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    readingviewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    return mFragmentView;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    adapter = new ReadingPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); //here used child fragment manager
}
```

ReadingPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            FragmentA tab1 =  FragmentA .newInstance("A");

        return tab1;
        case 1:

            FragmentB tab2 =  FragmentB.newInstance("B");

            return tab2;

        default:
            return null;
    }
```

HomeActivity

```
private void ChangeFragment(BaseFragment fragment, String title, boolean isReplace) {
  //  mTitleTextView.setText(title);
    this.fragment = fragment;
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out, android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);

    if (isReplace) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(CURRENT_TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

this is how I am changing the fragments

Comment: You fragment will reload. Hence it's advisable to save the state of the clicked view. Then populate when reloading again.

Comment: You have only posted how you have created the viewpager and not how you are opening the other fragment on button click, which i guess is the real problem. Anyway I guess `FragmentTransaction.hide()` can help you in this.

Comment: @Hussain other fragment is opening when an item in the expandablelist clicks

Comment: Use `hide()` to hide the fragment containing viewpager and `add()` to load the fragment you want to open with backstack `null`

Comment: it was my mistake.I was replacing my fragment all the time instead of adding fragment.